# How to use ScrollIntoView in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **DataGrid** with many items (rows) and I need to programmatically scroll to the bottom.
I have searched on stackoverflow and google and it seems the solution is **ScrollIntoView**, but I don't know how to get it to work. I tried:

```
dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid1.Items.Count()); 

dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(100);
```

The documentation says the bracket inside the ScrollIntoView is an Item Object. How can I get the last row as an object? (e.g. **dataGrid.Items.LastRow()**??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `dataGrid.Items[ dataGrid.Items.Count-1 ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just going to leave this here as an example, so that another idiot like myself doesn't have to spend 10 minutes linking the question and the top answer.

```
dg_address.ScrollIntoView(dg_address.Items[dg_address.Items.Count - 1]);
```